# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix - namespace error

Tags: android, xml, parsing

There's something wrong with my xml file. I know it's something connected with namespaces.
I wrote this [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-b) and tried to do some magic, but that still doesn't work.
As You see I marked **Linear Layout** with **x,a,b,c,d,e**

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/llDetailsRowLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlTaskTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bar_task_checklist_blue"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/task_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_seperator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/seperator"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_seperator"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/id_string"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iTaskStatusButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@drawable/task_sort_icon_selector"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/task_sort_icon_selector" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/test6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iCalendar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@drawable/calendar_blue"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/calendar_blue" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/date_string"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iClock"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@drawable/clock_blue"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/clock_blue" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/time_string"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iLocation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@drawable/pinplace_blue"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pinplace_blue" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/address_string"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="11sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="onDescriptionClick"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/task_description"
                        android:textColor="@color/my_black"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/map_box" >

                <fragment
                    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    map:mapType="normal"
                    map:uiCompass="true"
                    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
                    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
                    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
                    map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Still got problem at map:

[image]

Comment: I really don't know about this `<x:LinearLayout>` what is this prefex `x`, is it valid?

Comment: @Pragnani: Prefix is just an alias and can be named anything syntactically valid. By convention, `android` is a prefix for `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` but it could as well be `windowsphone`. However, the problem here is that `x` etc. are not declared.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the namespace prefixes `x`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` that are not declared.

Generally, namespace prefix `x` would be declared as `xmlns:x="http://some.schema.somewhere"` attribute in an element where the prefix is used. However, you don't need to use namespaces for Android XML tags. You do need namespaces for attributes though, and in your XML there are two namespaces for those: `android` and `map`.

There's also a duplicate `android` namespace declaration as noticed by @Pragnani.

Comment: but there's still problem with xmlns map
screen bellow\

Comment: @krzakov: what's the error on the `xmlns:map` row in your updated question?