# Attribute is missing Android namespace prefix on listview

Tags: java, android, xml, namespaces

I am creating an android app which uses a schedule_layout.xml file located under the res folder but I'm getting this error, "Android is missing Android namespace prefix". What does it mean? How can I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

Comment: you are missing this: xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" //missing
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

Also check this

[Why this line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" must be the first in the layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-b)

Comment: @koneko you are welcome do check the link in my post

Answer (score 2):

add the following attribute to your list view:

`"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

it's like a namespace declaration