# The meaning of sentence in head of XML

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

When I made android application, I see sentence in head of XML File. But I don't know the meaning of it.

Comment: which line are you talking about?

Comment: Top of XML file. exam> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743250/meaning-of-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743250/meaning-of-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8/27398439#27398439 for the first part, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

Quoting from the link above

The first line is the XML declaration. It defines the XML version (1.0).

Also check

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
```

Its a `LinearLayout` that you have in xml

xmlns- its xml name space

A quick search on the same topic on stackoverflow gives the below links which should anser your question

[Why this line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" must be the first in the layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-b)

[What does "xmlns" in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about this line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

That line actually defines the version of .xml file.

Please refer to [XML Standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/)

Comment: so, how about this?  <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: It is declaration of LinearLayout.

Comment: @윤시완 that means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-b

Answer (score 0):

In xml Header  this is `?xml version="1.0"` the xml **VERSION** you are defining. This is the **ENCODING TYPE** of xml to be defined `encoding="utf-8"?` . And this is the **NAMESPACE** of xml `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` hope this help.