# WebView tag in xml shows error in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, webview

why is layout xml file rejecting WebView tag.
Red circle with cross is displayed in line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
and application can not be started.

Thank you

Comment: If you hover over the red cross it'll display the error. Can you tell us what it is ?

Comment: it says:Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you've put the xmlns tag in the webview, something like this:

```
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Change it to

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The xmlns:android tag should only be added to the outermost layout.

As to why we use xmlns:android, Read : [Why this line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" must be the first in the layout xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-be)

Comment: Many thanks! It was working when WebView was the only tag in layout, but when I put it into LinearLayout, error appeared. Thank you so much for your quick answer!