# Android Studio XML code issue

Tags: android, xml

why do I get
 *xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"*

after the text view class when I'm trying to run the basic XML code?

On android studio, it runs fine with it, but on Udacity ( where I'm learning from ) it's not a part of code.

Comment: Why don't you ask Udacity Forum?

Comment: What even is "the basic XML code"? Please [edit] your question with more information

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-be

Answer (score 0):

When you use
android:id="@+id/yourViewId"
You are actually calling:
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:id

You can also call other namespaces like app and tools.

You can find more information here: [Android XML Namespaces](http://myhexaville.com/2017/07/26/android-xml-namespaces/)