# how to access http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-namespaces

When developing android, we usually use xml when developing a layout file.

example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
```

I have a query at that point.
How to access http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ?

As I found some information.
I know that is not a URL, it is URI. So can not access through the internet. Then where is namespace information? How can access that information?

Comment: Do you want to access to RelativeLayout in your code I am right?

Comment: "How to access http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ? -- you don't. There has never been a Web page at that URL. "Then where is namespace information?" -- what do you mean by "namespace information"?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119359/why-this-line-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-must-be

Comment: The namespace defines the attribute names within the XML. If you are looking for information as to their use you might look at the _XML Attributes_ and _Inherited XML attributes_ sections in the [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference?hl=en). e.g. [TextView#xml-attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#xml-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following URI is a **namespace name**, according to [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

In section **[3 Declaring Namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl)**, it is stated that:

> The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, SHOULD have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists).

Some XMLs have no schema. In such XMLs, you can't have it.

The goal of namespace names is to avoid collisions in element names and attribute names. XMLs use URIs as namespace names for their uniqueness and persistence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.